# Looking for an X-Men animated TV show

Tags: story-identification, x-men

Okay, this might not be an easy one - I saw one scene from this TV show at a friend's house a while back and haven't been able to get it out of my head.  Now that I've seen most of the X-Men movies, I'd be interested in finding this show.

My details are unfortunately not many.  This was an animated TV show with the X-Men, and I remember the exact scene: something was going on with Nightcrawler, and he went to this place to meet up with a person who claimed to know him, I think.  The reveal was that the person was Mystique, and she removed her hood and called Nightcrawler "son."  Nightcrawler said "No. No!" and then a fight broke out - I think that some of the X-men followed Nightcrawler and Mystique had some with her.  The only detail I remember was that Rogue was in the fight, and she drained someone and put them to sleep.  I can't remember any of the other X-men that were in the show.

It could've just been the one episode, but from what I saw this seemed to be a more serious show, not one aimed at a really young audience.  It wasn't anime, but the animation was pretty crisp.

I know I don't have a lot of details, but I would love to find this show again if anyone recognizes it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am guessing this is X-Men Evolution.  It was not a series I watched, but it doesn’t seem to match the X-Men cartoons I did watch, and I saw something that resembled your description in this video at 1:14.

Comment: +1 for the answer. However, you could improve it. Add the synopsis/plot of this episode because the Youtube videos may get removed which will make your answer quite useless.

Comment: Yep, that definitely looks like it!  Thanks!